# Codesplit using Router gives 'init is not a function' error

Tags: reactjs

I want to execute React Codesplit. I have followed the documentation given by React, but there seems to be showing a 'init is not a function' error:

[image: TypeError: init is not a function]

Here's my code:

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const Privacy = lazy(() => import('./pages/PrivacyPolicies'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('./pages'));

const App = () => (
<Router>
  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy}/>
  </Switch>
  </Suspense>
</Router>
);

export default App;
```

... and here's the relevant section of my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.7.0",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "html-react-parser": "0.0.4",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "react-card-flip": "^1.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
    "react-progressive-graceful-image": "^0.6.13",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0"
  }
```

Comment: What's the React version you're using?

Comment: @raina77ow 17.0.2

Comment: Got it; what's got imported by `./pages`? Could you show how the imported modules look like (by cutting all the details and leaving just the signatures essentially)?

Comment: @raina77ow Do you mean what's the export made by the index.js in the pages? it's 'export default Home'. Whereas, for the PrivacyPolicies folder's index.js, it's export default PrivacyPolicy

Comment: @raina77ow could you please look into this. We have tried everything that we could have :/

Comment: You basically ask to debug your code without giving additional information - stacktrace, code of components etc. It doesn't work this way.

Comment: @raina77ow Find attached the error's image. Let me know which exact component's image you require, I can take such images for all of them. I could send over the zip of the project too. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17qN29iuveMN_jmlL7VwXbJbBYI20rcFM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please remove the links; it's not really a good practice to share your code with the rest of internets. :) I added the relevant parts of your project to the question's text, as well as provided an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using incompatible versions of `react-dom` and `react` packages: the former is ^17.0.2, the latter is ^16.14.0. While the difference might seem subtle, it's substantial enough to break.

The solution is simple: either install a newer version of React (you should save it as a regular dependency, not as a dev one), or downgrade the rest of libraries to 16.x.

Comment: I just cannot thank you enough man!!! I checked the version of react before using npm view react version, which showed it to be the latest version. But you were right! thank you!!

Comment: Then you didn't check them properly. Actually you don't have these files sitting somewhere - they're part of your build. And while there are some tricks to make build work with a different version of a package than the one specified in package(-lock).json, none of them are in use in your project.

Comment: Glad this is resolved. Dependency mismatch is a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks a lottt!!! But why doesn't the latest version of react and react-dom support React.lazy?

Comment: That's the irony: they both support it, but in a different way. React.lazy support was added to React package [in 16.6](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html) (almost 3 years ago), but here's how the team works: they _experiment_, and adjust the code based on the users' feedback. That's why it's rarely a good idea introducing new shiny features of React ecosystem in your production systems immediately after those features are introduced: usually, they just need time to mature.